# label inside stack view in ios not displaying any content when lengthy content appears

Tags: ios, uilabel, xcode8, ios-autolayout, uistackview

Inside my main view there is a scroll view. Inside it is a vertical stack view containing three horizontal stack views. The outer stack view alignment is set to leading and distribution is set to fill. and it is pinned with margins of 8 each from its superview. The inside horizontal stack views have alignment top and distribution set to fill. The problem is that if any label inside the horizontal stack view has a content spanning more than a few characters all the labels doesnt display any content.

Comment: can you paste some code how you have configured the stackview

Comment: I figured out the problem. I had made my main view as scroll view. Now I want to embed it into a view. How to do that?

Comment: why isnt multi line label in a stack view not being allowed inside a scroll view

Comment: stackview is instance of uiview so it can be added as subview to any view .

Comment: there must be some problem with constraints when you add to scrollview,do you get any messages in log console

Comment: No My constraints are absoloutely fine. I can share the screen with u

Comment: have you added number of lines > 0 for uilabel if yes  try adding this textLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;

Comment: I solved it. The conclusion is that your outermost view should not be scrollview otherwise it wont allow multiline labels